# sort an array of objects on multiple key using array-sort

Tags: arrays, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a requirement where the array of objects needs to be sorted on certain keys. The keys with which it needs to be sorted is dynamic and it is Not fixed.
I came across array-sort in npm library. Using that, am able to sort on multiple keys but it sorts only on ascending order.

```
const input = [{id:'1',name:'John',city:'Denver',State:'CO'},
               {id:'2',name:'Smith',city:'San Fransisco',State:'CA'},
               {id:'3',name:'Adam',city:'Concord',State:'CA'},
               {id:'1',name:'John',city:'Concord',State:'CA'}]
```

I want to sort on State (asc), city (asc) and id (desc). My output should look like

```
[
 {id:'3',name:'Adam',city:'Concord',State:'CA'},
 {id:'1',name:'John',city:'Concord',State:'CA'},
 {id:'2',name:'Smith',city:'San Fransisco',State:'CA'}, 
 {id:'1',name:'John',city:'Denver',State:'CO'}]
```

Can anyone please let me know how i can implement sorting on descending using array-sort

Thanks

Comment: Which language you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want a JavaScript function like this?

```js
function multicolumnSort(data, orders) {
    return data.sort((e1, e2) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < orders.length; i++)
            if (e1[orders[i].column] != e2[orders[i].column])
                return orders[i].desc ^ e2[orders[i].column] < e1[orders[i].column]? 1 : -1;
        return 0;
    });
}
```

Then, you may call the function with your order keys:

```js
let orders = [
    {
        column: 'State'
    },
    {
        column: 'city'
    },
    {
        column: 'id',
        desc: true
    }
];

let result = multicolumnSort(input, orders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check my code

```js
function DESC(i, ii) { // DESC
  return (i[key] > ii[key]) ? -1 : ((i[key] < ii[key]) ? 1 : 0);
}

function ASC(i, ii) { // ASC
  return (i[key] > ii[key]) ? 1 : ((i[key] < ii[key]) ? -1 : 0);
}



function StartSort(data, myArray, order) {
  // data - row for sorting, array - array fo sorting, order - order of sorting
  key = data;
  arr = myArray;
  if (order.toUpperCase() == "ASC") {
    sortedArray = arr.sort(ASC);
  } else {
    sortedArray = arr.sort(DESC);
  }
  return sortedArray;
}

//sorting started

const input = [{
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    city: 'Denver',
    State: 'CO'
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    name: 'Smith',
    city: 'San Fransisco',
    State: 'CA'
  },
  {
    id: '3',
    name: 'Adam',
    city: 'Concord',
    State: 'CA'
  },
  {
    id: '1',
    name: 'John',
    city: 'Concord',
    State: 'CA'
  }
]



let output1 = StartSort('state', input, 'ASC');
output1 = StartSort('city', output1, 'ASC');
output1 = StartSort('id', output1, 'DESC');



console.log(output1);
```